# Create new record in Sequelize without duplicating content in source model

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a database that stores authors and books. One author has many books. When I create a new book by an author that already exists, I need to find the author first and then manually input the author_id into the new book I am trying to create. Is there a way that Sequelize allows you to do this without having to find the author first?

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mylibrary', 'isabellachen', 'projectorion', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres',
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

const User = sequelize.define('author', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

const Book = sequelize.define('book', {
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  genre: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

User.Book = User.hasMany(Book, { foriegnKey: 'authorId' })
Book.User = Book.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'author'
})

// User.sync({ force: true });
// Book.sync({ force: true });

Book.create({
  title: 'Pale Blue Dot',
  genre: 'non-fiction',
  author: { firstName: 'Carl', lastName: 'Sagan' }
}, {
    include: [{
      model: User,
      as: 'author'
    }]
  }
)

const createBook2 = async () => {
  const author = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      firstName: "Carl",
      lastName: "Sagan"
    },
  });

  Book.create({
    title: 'Pale Blue Dot',
    genre: 'non-fiction',
    authorId: author.id
  }, {
      include: [{
        model: User,
        as: 'author'
      }]
    }
  )
}




sequelize.sync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once we have defined `User.hasMany(Books)`, we can use the associated functions to create new `Books`. In this case, `create` can be used.

```
const author = User.find({// search condition} 
author.createBook({title: 'Pale Blue Dot', 'genre: 'non-fiction'}
```